# simple expressjs PUT handler with jQuery ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm building a web application that uses a REST API for communication with the server, built in Node.js using Expres.js. The problem is that I can't seem to read the request body in the `PUT` requests. My client side code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/model/"+this.database,
    type: "PUT",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: this.model.exportJSON(),
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and the server side code (only the important bits):

```
//in the main file
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var model = require("./apis/model");

app.put("/api/model/:model", model.put);

app.listen(8000);

//in the module
module.exports = {    
    put: function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body);
        res.json({"hello": "world"});
    }
};
```

The exportJSON method on the model produces an object, not anything empty, but on the server side console.log I get `undefined`, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The Chrome developer console reveals that the data is sent just fine, so it has to be something on the server side

Comment: Try doing `data: JSON.stringify(this.model.exportJSON())`

Comment: Already tried that, but it gave me the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are sending a content type of 'application/json', you need to add the `body-parser` middleware:

```
$ npm install body-parser
```

And then use it thusly:

```
//in the main file
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var body = require('body-parser');

app.use(body.json());

app.put("/api/model/:model", function (req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({"hello": "world"});
});

app.listen(8000);
```

And then make the request

```
$ curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{ "key": "value" }' http://localhost:8000/api/model/foo
```

And this will log

```
{ "key" : "value" }
```

Make sure you are defining the `app.use(body)` call BEFORE you define a route.

Comment: I used the bodyparser, and i changed it to `app.use(bodyParser.json());` because otherwise it would give me a deprecation warning and the page wouldn't load. However, it still returns undefined